# Linkage Error while Consuming apache-cxf Web Services in Liferay 7

Tags: linux, soap, java-8, cxf, liferay-7

I am trying to consume apache-cxf Web Services In Liferay-7 portlet ,I got the following error in linux environment.

13:39:14,374 ERROR [http-nio-4080-exec-9][status_jsp:950] com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: com/sun/org/apache/xpath/internal/jaxp/XPathImpl

If I run the same portlet in liferay 7 windows environment it is working fine

And here is the sample jsp code (view.jsp)

```
<portlet:defineObjects />
<%@ page import="org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.endpoint.dynamic.JaxWsDynamicClientFactory" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%

String endpoint="http://*******/***-ws/soap/login?wsdl";
String method ="login";
String uname ="admin";
String pwd = "admin";
String result = "";

Object[] params = new Object[2] ;
params[0] = (Object)uname;
params[1] = (Object)pwd;

result = call(endpoint, method, params);
System.out.println("Result : "+result);
%>
<%!

public static  String call(String endpoint, String method, Object[] params) {

JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();

try {
    Client client = dcf.createClient(endpoint);
    System.out.println("Client Object Create successfully  :");
    Object[]  returnVals = client.invoke(method, params);
    //extract returned value. getting 1st value as sakai ws calls returns only one value.
    if(returnVals!=null && returnVals.length>0)
        return (String)returnVals[0];
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("A connection error occurred: " + e.getClass() + ": " + e.getMessage());
}
return null;
}
%>
```

The Problem is occurring at
**Client client = dcf.createClient(endpoint);**

Here is the dependencies we are using

==============================

cxf-core-3.1.8.jar

cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.8.jar

cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.8.jar

cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.8.jar

cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.8.jar

cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.8.jar

cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.8.jar

neethi-3.0.3.jar

==============================

Same Code I have checked in Liferay 6.2 and  its  working fine in both windows and linux environment, but I have added some more jar files.

==============================

cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.1.8.jar

cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.1.8.jar

cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.1.8.jar

jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar

jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar

xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar

stax2-api-3.1.4.jar

woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar

wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar

==============================

Please Help me out .

Thanks & Regards,

P.V.B.Raju.

Comment: How do you package your app? Do you use WARs? OSGi Bundles? Fat OSGi jars?

Comment: We are using plugin-portlet(WAR)

Comment: Linux and windows load the lib in different order maybe there is a required sequence in which the libraries need to be loaded to make it work. This could be caused by having too many implementations on the classpath and things get overridden. Also, I would consider the OSGi approach in developing plugins.

Comment: we tried to implement the same thing in modular approach,

Comment: could you paste the Gradle/maven file in here with the dep definitions?

Comment: By default the module is not getting started ,

So we tried to start it manually from gogo shell,
when i'm doing this i got following log,

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: SampleCXFModule [8199]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.cxf.endpoint; version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"

Comment: build.gradle:
`compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-core', version: '3.1.8'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-bindings-soap', version: '3.1.8'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb', version: '3.1.8'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws', version: '3.1.8'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-frontend-simple', version: '3.1.8'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-transports-http', version: '3.1.8'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-wsdl', version: '3.1.8'`

Comment: if you use bundles you have 2 options how to get dependencies either you create a fat jar and bundle all dep code inside your jar file or you need to deploy the dependencies separately. If you using the WAR approach the jar files are included in the jar.

Comment: when you compile your WAR files what are all the dependencies that get into the lib folder? Is there something that does not look right like spring libraries?

Comment: Hi @MiroslavLigas,
I got it what your trying to say about,
please look at my above comments and give me some suggestions on, what i did wrong in my module.?
Why the module is not starting.?

Comment: I tried to recreate your project. I created a bundle and added your code + dependencies. I was trying to create a fat jar to bundle everything in but I did not have a lot of time to look into it. It turns out that cxf libraries have tons of dependencies. Basically, a way to go is to list all dependencies in the bnd.bnd file with -includeresource: @LIB-NAME-[0-9]*.jar,... until the bundle resolves. A way to make the exercise easier is to use only the necessary libraries. I have a look at it again in the evening.

Comment: Hi @ Miroslav Ligas,
Have you checked my code could you please help me out

Comment: Hi sorry I was busy but I will look at it during the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the war approach and it worked fine. I tested in on Liferay 7 DXP FP 32.

See my test code. https://github.com/mir333/cxf-test-demo

The jar approach is a bit more tricky because you need to list all necessary libraries in Gradle and bnd file. Basically, everything that is in the war files lib folder would need to be inserted there and if you get still a missing import message you need to find a lib that provides the package and add it as well.

Have a look at this blog post it explains how to do it and it refers to another blog post have a look at it also. https://web.liferay.com/web/sushil.patidar/blog/-/blogs/liferay-osgi-module-project-dependency-resolution

EDIT:
New tooling becomes available for this. Have a look at https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/adding-third-party-libraries-to-a-module#embedding-libraries-using-gradle make sure you are on the right Gradle plugin.

Comment: Hi @Miroslav,

Thanks for your reply.

I'm unable use your test code in liferay 7 GA2. could you please elaborate how can deploy it.

And regarding module jar approach,

i tried with adding dependency jar's list under -includeresource:\
in bnd.bnd file, later when i deploy the module it's showing Can not find JAR file 'asm-[0-9].jar', cxf-rt-ws-addr-[0-9].jar,jaxb-impl-[0-9]*.jar etc..
could you please tell me the way to fix it.

Thanks,
P.V.B Raju.

Comment: the code should compile file just clone repo run the gulp build and copy the war file into the deploy folder. If you have an error in the log while deploying on GA2 let me know. Also, note that GA2 is quite old and you should update.

Comment: I cloned the repo from git but as per my knowledge gulp build for theme type of plugin not for portlet/module so I stucked with deployment ,could you please help me out.

Comment: sry typo, I met gradle of course. The wrapper is included.

Comment: yeah by using  war approach its working fine,and I am trying to do in jar approach but  while listing the libraries in gradle and  bnd file I am facing dependency problems.could you please help me out.

Comment: not really. follow the steps in the blog post and add all dependencies. The library that you chose thas a lot of baggage so you need to sort it out. Alternatively, try to find a multi-bundle that works for you. Apache sometimes distributes OSGi bundles that contain all the dependencies so you are going to have just one big dependency.

Comment: have a look at this https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/adding-third-party-libraries-to-a-module#embedding-libraries-using-gradle it seems that LFR provided new tooling that could resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

My approach was different. I installed the necessary Apache CXF modules as an OSGi bundle on the Liferay instance, after which I built a simple WS client using the CXF APIs exported to the OSGi container. Apache CXF modules installed as OSGIi bundle.

- Apache XmlSchema Core (v. 2.2.1)
- Apache CXF Core
- Apache CXF Runtime JAXB DataBinding
- Apache CXF Runtime XML Binding
- Apache CXF Runtime SOAP Binding
- Apache CXF Runtime Core for WSDL
- Apache CXF Runtime Simple Frontend
- Apache CXF Runtime JAX-WS Frontend
- Apache CXF Runtime HTTP Transport

The installation of the nine elements of the Apache CXF framework can be performed by connecting via telnet to the Apache Felix GoGo Shell. Once the Liferay 7 portal is running, the Apache CXF framework can be installed by executing the commands install $URL_CXF_BUNDLE

For more information you can read this article [Liferay 7: Come realizzare un client SOAP con Apache CXF in OSGi Style](https://www.dontesta.it/2016/07/19/liferay-7-come-realizzare-un-client-soap-apache-cxf-osgi-style/)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the information. I tried reading the article in the link above which is not in English. Do you have an English version? Thanks so much.

Comment: @VC1 No, only italian language. Sorry.